# Ampersand is cloning itself when switching between mobile and full site themes with a querystring

Tags: bug, mobile-web

Steps to reproduce:

1. Search for something, e.g. https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=unicorn
2. Click "mobile" link in the footer
3. URL will now be `https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=unicorn&__=R`
   <sub>(R - some cache busting random number, not relevant)</sub>
4. Click "full site" link in footer
5. URL will now be `https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=unicorn&&__=R`
6. Repeat steps 2-5 to have the `&` clone itself happily ever after.

Minor, but still a bug.